# GraphQL 'CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL output type' error while using TypeGraphQL and TypeORM

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql, node.js-typeorm

I'm trying to execute simple query using GraphQL with TypeORM and TypeScript which would fetch every record from database Photo table, but I'm getting this error:

> CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for 'photos' of 'photosResolver' class. Is the value, that is
> used as its TS type or explicit type,
> decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper output value?

How to fix this error? What am I doing wrong?

index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { photosResolver } from "./resolvers/photos";

const main = async () => {
  const connection = await createConnection();

  const app = express();
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [
        photosResolver
      ]
    })
  });

  apolloServer.start().then(() => apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app }));

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Server started on localhost:4000");
  });
  
}

main().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Photo entity

```
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from "type-graphql";
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Photo extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column({ length: 20 })
  name: string;
}
```

Resolver

```
import { Resolver, Query } from "type-graphql";
import { Photo } from "../entity/Photo";

@Resolver()
export class photosResolver {
  @Query(() => [Photo])
  photos() {
    return Photo.find();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure this will fix but the find() method should be async and return await Photo.find()p

Comment: @Jerome await return Photo.find() throws an error :  'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.'

Comment: because you need declare ```async photo(){return await Photo.find()}```